# Extra tags in project file when converting from VS2005 to VS2010

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, migration

I converted a project from VS2005 to VS2010.  The .csproj file now contains these tags:

```
 <FileUpgradeFlags></FileUpgradeFlags>
 <OldToolsVersion>2.0</OldToolsVersion>
 <UpgradeBackupLocation />
```

I don't plan to roll back to the old version, nor to run the project in multiple versions of VS. There are no errors compiling the project, and it appears to run normally. 
What is the purpose of these tags?  Is it safe to remove them?

Comment: I do it, don't worry nothing happen.